# Issue with query performance after enabling compression in TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, compression, database-performance, timescaledb

We've been experimenting with TimescaleDB, primarily on compression to address our disk space issues. However, we noticed an increase in query execution time after enabling compression.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  actions
WHERE
  task = '5uTTiGqdqLKUFwo6WXTC1V8tM6PekW6gmDGaKrNPPfNz'
  AND kind = 'CALL'
  AND args ->> 'method_name' = 'open'

# Postgresql table
Planning Time: 1.057 ms
Execution Time: 0.088 ms

# Hypertable with compression enabled
Planning Time: 33.903 ms
Execution Time: 1860.641 ms
```

Table schema:

```
Table "public.actions"
Column     |    Type     | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+---------
task       | text        |           | not null |
index      | integer     |           | not null |
from       | text        |           |          |
to         | text        |           |          |
created_at | bigint      |           | not null |
kind       | action_kind |           |          |
args       | jsonb       |           |          |
Indexes:
"actions_created_at_idx" btree (created_at DESC)
"actions_task_args_method_name_idx" btree (task, (args ->> 'method_name'::text)) WHERE kind = 'CALL'::kind
"actions_task_index_idx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (task, index, created_at)
```

Queries used for creating the hypertable & setting the compression policy:

```
SELECT
  create_hypertable(
    'actions',
    'created_at',
    migrate_data = > true,
    chunk_time_interval = > 604800000000000
  );

ALTER TABLE
  actions_hypertable_chunk
SET
  (timescaledb.compress);

SELECT
  add_compression_policy(
    'actions',
    BIGINT '604800000000000'
  );
```

Query plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
Append  (cost=0.04..64086.09 rows=12709000 width=14) (actual time=0.470..1859.661 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=276533 read=28627
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=153.380
  ->  Custom Scan (DecompressChunk) on _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_25_chunk  (cost=0.04..12.90 rows=290000 width=10) (actual time=0.149..0.150 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: _hyper_3_25_chunk.to
        Filter: ((_hyper_3_25_chunk.task = '5uTTiGqdqLKUFwo6WXTC1V8tM6PekW6gmDGaKrNPPfNz'::text) AND (_hyper_3_25_chunk.kind = 'CALL'::kind) AND ((_hyper_3_25_chunk.args ->> 'method_name'::text) = 'open'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 42
        Buffers: shared hit=34
        ->  Seq Scan on _timescaledb_internal.compress_hyper_5_69_chunk  (cost=0.00..12.90 rows=290 width=132) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.task, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.index, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.from, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.to, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.created_at, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.kind, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk.args, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk._ts_meta_count, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk._ts_meta_sequence_num, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk._ts_meta_min_1, compress_hyper_5_69_chunk._ts_meta_max_1
              Buffers: shared hit=1

  ...

  ->  Custom Scan (DecompressChunk) on _timescaledb_internal._hyper_3_68_chunk  (cost=0.03..7.13 rows=213000 width=18) (actual time=132.736..132.736 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: _hyper_3_68_chunk.to
        Filter: ((_hyper_3_68_chunk.task = '5uTTiGqdqLKUFwo6WXTC1V8tM6PekW6gmDGaKrNPPfNz'::text) AND (_hyper_3_68_chunk.kind = 'CALL'::kind) AND ((_hyper_3_68_chunk.args ->> 'method_name'::text) = 'open'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 212419
        Buffers: shared hit=24692
        ->  Seq Scan on _timescaledb_internal.compress_hyper_5_112_chunk  (cost=0.00..7.13 rows=213 width=132) (actual time=0.010..0.087 rows=213 loops=1)
              Output: compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.task, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.index, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.from, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.to, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.created_at, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.kind, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk.args, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk._ts_meta_count, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk._ts_meta_sequence_num, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk._ts_meta_min_1, compress_hyper_5_112_chunk._ts_meta_max_1
              Buffers: shared hit=5
Query Identifier: -1707176995114799452
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=12972 dirtied=1
Planning Time: 33.903 ms
Execution Time: 1860.641 ms
```

We have noticed the decompression of chunks from the execution plan. Is that a problem? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the query execution time?

Comment: Compression is all about trading performance for space conservation, so why are you surprised by that?

Comment: Is it common to experience a slowdown in query performance when enabling compression? We haven't used compression previously. Are there any specific optimizations we should apply within TimescaleDB to enhance query speed? Is it possible to access data without the need for decompression?

Comment: I don't know TimescaleDB; mine was just a general observation. How do you expect to access compressed data without decompressing them? Perhaps you should forget about compression and invest a little money into extra storage.

Comment: What is the explain plan for the uncompressed data?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid decompressing all data to just check the condition of a few columns, you set this columns to the [segmentby](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/compression/alter_table_compression/#optional-arguments) option.

Always remember to configure `segmentby` and `orderby`to have more query performance later.

```sql
ALTER TABLE
  actions_hypertable_chunk
SET
  (timescaledb.compress, timescaledb.compress_segmentby="task, kind"
```

For the `(_hyper_3_68_chunk.args ->> 'method_name'::text))` that seems to be always equal to `"open"` maybe a conditional index would be better.